# How to define a simple model for a complex TreeView<T> in JavaFX 8?

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-8

> **TLDR**: How to implement JavaFX 8 [TreeItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) in a [TreeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html) with
> different object types?

I have XML configuration with the following object structure.

`[Configuration]` `--- has 1-n --->` `[Group]` `--- has 1-n --->` `[Topic]`

I would like to display this structure in a [TreeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html) like follows.

```
Groups
|
+-- Group A
|    |-- Topic A
|    |-- Topic B
|
+-- Group B
     |-- Topic C
     |-- Topic D
```

After reading the [TreeItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) documentation I just can't think of a solution because the objects in my structure are not of the same type and so I can't just define a `TreeItem<T>` with `TreeItem<File>` like in the example at [TreeItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html).

I would like to know how to define a well designed model for the above structure which meets following requirements.

- display different context menu based on class type of the leaf
- possibility to insert and delete leafs at any level of the tree
- easy access to leaf objects so that I can call getters/setters on them
- tree auto update when the model changes

Any solutions or good articles with an existing solution?

Comment: treeView/Item is single type ... no support for mixing: at the worst, the type must be <Object>

Comment: @kleopatra It seems like bad design but I went with <Object> and it works. Feel free to make an answer from it and I will accept it.

Comment: you can self-answer if you think it's worth an answer :-)

Comment: [You either could look at this, it's another example][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752549/different-behaviour-for-treeitem-javafx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after @kleopatra (thanks a lot) pointed me to use the type `<Object>` I did it as follows.

```
public class TreeController implements Initializable {

    ...

    @FXML
    private TreeView<Object> treeView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        TreeItem<Object> root = new TreeItem<>("Groups");

        for (Object object : cfg.getGroupList()) {
            root.getChildren().add(createNode(object));
        }

        treeView.setRoot(root);
        treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new TreeCellFactory());

        root.setExpanded(true);
    }

    private TreeItem<Object> createNode(Object o) {
        return new TreeItem<Object>(o) {
            private boolean isLeaf;
            private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
            private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

            @Override
            public ObservableList<TreeItem<Object>> getChildren() {
                if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
                    isFirstTimeChildren = false;

                    super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren(this));
                }
                return super.getChildren();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLeaf() {
                if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
                    isFirstTimeLeaf = false;

                    if (o instanceof Topic) {
                        isLeaf = true;
                    }
                }

                return isLeaf;
            }

            private ObservableList<TreeItem<Object>> buildChildren(TreeItem<Object> treeItem) {
                if (treeItem.getValue() instanceof Group) {
                    ObservableList<TreeItem<Object>> children = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                    for (Object object : ((Group) treeItem.getValue()).getTopicList()) {
                        children.add(createNode(object));
                    }

                    return children;
                }

                return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
            }
        };
    }

    private final class TreeCellFactory extends TreeCell<Object> {
        private ContextMenu topicMenu = new ContextMenu();
        private ContextMenu groupMenu = new ContextMenu();

        public TreeCellFactory() {
            MenuItem topicMenuItem = new MenuItem("- Item 1 -");
            topicMenu.getItems().add(topicMenuItem);

            MenuItem groupMenuItem = new MenuItem("- Item 1 -");
            groupMenu.getItems().add(groupMenuItem);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
            }

            if (item instanceof Topic) {
                setContextMenu(topicMenu);
            }

            if (item instanceof Group) {
                setContextMenu(groupMenu);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Please note that I overwrite `toString()` in `Topic` and `Group` to a text which I want to appear on the tree leafs.